# Second derivative implicit differentiation using Wolfram Alpha input?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, calculus-and-analysis

How would you perform second derivative implicit differentiation using Wolfram Alpha input?  The reason that I'm using WA input is that it gives you step-by-step solutions and I'm a first year calculus student trying to figure things out.

I've tried all of the obvious queries that I can think of without getting the desired results.  If I type just the equation in it will give the results I'm seeking but without the step-by-step solution since it is not the primary output for the query.

Here's an example of the results I get from just entering the equation x^2 + xy = 5  (w/desired result circled):

[image: equation results]

*****P.S. Cross posted to [community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/283665?p_p_auth=kD3FBYSv](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/283665?p_p_auth=kD3FBYSv) ***

Comment: fyi, cross posted http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/283665?p_p_auth=kD3FBYSv  please mention this in your question on both sites so not to waste people time duplicating answers and efforts.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: If you're using *Mathematica*, why do this on W|A?

Comment: @MichaelE2, the answer to your question is in my original post.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, but "Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Questions on Wolfram Alpha..." (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  This does not seem to be a question on using *Mathematica*, either to access W|A or to process its results.

Comment: BTW, entering "Find dy/dx if x^2 + xy = 5" into W|A works, although I expect it's been so long that's not really of use to you now. :) Besides, W|A has gone through several upgrades, too. It might handle impl. diff. better now than four years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
D[x^2 + x y[x] == 5, {x, 1}]
sol1 = Solve[%, y'[x]]
D[x^2 + x y[x] == 5, {x, 2}]
sol2 = Solve[%, y''[x]]
sol2 /. sol1 // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but Wolfram Alpha doesn't recognize that and entering it as Mathematica input doesn't give me the step-by-step solution that I'm seeking.

Comment: @GaryWhite I think my answer is a step by step solution for this example,if you learn something in your calculus class.

Comment: Yes, I see that and I do appreciate your help. Unfortunately, this is still not what I'm looking for. The Wolfram Alpha step-by-step solutions are more granular and come with text explaining each step.

Comment: @Gary If you want the most "granular" thing: Stay with `Wolfram Alpha` (although I think that your question received a nice answer).